# How to prevent macos from switching the windows of the external display and the main screen at the same time?

Tags: macos

For example, both screens have maximized edge and Chrome windows, edge1, chrome1 in primary monitor and edge2, chrome2 in extend monitor. whether I use command+tab, click the icon in the dock, or use the control center, switching from edge1 to chrome1 on one screen will always cause the other screen to display the chrome2 window . How to make the two screens switch their windows independently without affecting the other screen?

“Displays have separate Spaces” switch is turned on but has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Open the "System Settings" app then click on "Displays". Change the display configuration to extended rather than mirror.

Comment: what i'm asking is about window, two window of an app, one window on each of the two monitors, switch to one window in one monitor will cause the other window display in the other monitor. It is of couse extend, not mirror.